# NextJS Middleware TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, middleware

I'm following an old tutorial that sets up a middleware in NextJS and the code on their end seems to work fine but the same block of code causes a NetworkError on my end. The problem is probably caused by the fact that the middleware interferes with either NextJS or webpack manager since these make requests at the very start of the page that my code redirects, causing the page to not load, but I don't know how to exclude these requests from the middleware.

I'm trying to achieve a basic middleware that redirects the user whenever they try to load a page to the login page if they have not logged in or the session has expired.

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req, res) {
    // token will exist if user is logged in
    const token = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET });
    
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

    // allow the request if the following is true...
    // 1. the token exists
    // 2. it's a request for next-auth session & provider fetching
    
    console.log("url: ", url.href);

    if (pathname.includes("/api/auth") || token) {
        console.log("login");
        return NextResponse.next();
    };

    // redirect to login if no token AND requesting protected route
    if (!token && pathname !== "/login") {
        console.log("redirect: ", pathname);
        return NextResponse.redirect(`${url.host}/login`);
    };

    console.log("fail: ", pathname);
}
```

I have tried this block of code to make an exception for requests coming from NextJS itself:

```
if (pathname.includes("/_next")) {
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

But it did not work.

Comment: If any exception prevents the middleware function from executing successfully, that may cause your browser to redirects an infinite times, thus leads to NetworkError. So maybe you should add a try/catch to detect and handle exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

When using any middlware, you should call `next()` function to give other middlewares and handlers control. Like this:

```js
export async function middleware(req, res, next) {
    // token will exist if user is logged in
    const token = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET });
    // ...
    next()
}
```